# Translating a messy date string in a DataFrame to `datetime` in python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a dataframe that lists the date in several formats. For example:

```
       date
201    July 17,2019
555    06-06-2019
295    28/3/2019
```

Is there a way to translate all of those dates to a `datetime`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Check `Edit` below for better answer.

Normally for a task like this you would use [`pandas.Series.dt.strftime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html#pandas-series-dt-strftime) to convert the entire column to a specific `DateTime` format, but since it seems you have different formats in different rows you should probably instead look into[`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

Traverse through that column of `Date` an through `if` (or `try`) statement's changes the dates (**pseudocode** for demonstration):

```py
for date in date_column:
    if "," in date:
        # strptime()
    elif "-" in date:
        # strptime()
    elif "/" in date:
        dt = datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%y")

    column_row = dt
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) is the `strftime()` format codes, which you will need to set the second param of the function.

---

### Edit

You may also do this by utilizing [`dateutil.parser.parse`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) (make sure to install it first via `pip install python-dateutil`):

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse

df['date'] = df.date.apply(parse)
```

So for example:

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def parse_date(date):
    if date is np.nan:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return parse(date)


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": [
            "July 17,2019",
            "06-06-2019",
            "28/3/2019",
            "12/3/19",
            "31-12-19",
            np.nan,
        ],
        "text": ["t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5", "t6"],
    }
)

df["date"] = df.date.apply(parse_date)
```

Which converts:

```
           date text
0  July 17,2019   t1
1    06-06-2019   t2
2     28/3/2019   t3
3       12/3/19   t4
4      31-12-19   t5
5           NaN   t6
```

to

```
        date text
0 2019-07-17   t1
1 2019-06-06   t2
2 2019-03-28   t3
3 2019-12-03   t4
4 2019-12-31   t5
5        NaT   t6
```

You can also accomplish the same as the function by using a `lambda` expression as following:

```py
df["date"] = df.date.apply(lambda date: np.nan if date is np.nan else parse(date))
```

Comment: Do you mean `date` instead of `column_row`? (BTW, thanks for this excellent suggestion.)

Comment: One more question: Some of the dates are listed as 15/2/2019 and other are listed as 12/2/19. Is there a way to catch them?

Comment: I've updated the answer above utilizing ideas from @oppressionslayer answer, as well as [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which is a powerful Python module that will do what you are looking for.

Comment: I ran this and I got '('Unknown string format:', 'nan')'. That's because some of the dates are nan.

Comment: I then ran a loop:
for date in df['registration_date']:
    if date == 'nan':
        date = np.nan
    else:
        date = date.apply(parse)

And got AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'apply'

Comment: Because `df.date` returns a `Series` object, while `for date in df["date"]` is returning a `str` object for the `date` variable. What you are looking to do is: `df["date"] = df.date.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x is np.nan else parse(x))`

Comment: That gives me another error:
ValueError: month must be in 1..12

Comment: Seems like there is somewhere in your `Series` where the month is screwed up (more than 12). See if you can catch the error when it happens and print out the exact row to more precisely debug the issue.

Comment: My dates are European style: 31-12-19.

Comment: I personally get no errors. Look at the updated example above.

Comment: I found the erroneous date in the dataframe. It didn't have a year. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Yup, no problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would create a an apply function that checks for a regex, and returns the datetime based on that regex, running through a list of if/elif commands and returning the result, something like:

```
def checkdate(x):
   if pd.Series(x).str.contains(r'\w+ \d+,\d+')[0]: 
     return datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%B %d,%Y') 
   #elif next str.contains, etc
   else:
     return np.nan

df.date.apply(checkdate)
```

sample out

```
0   2019-07-17
1          NaT
2          NaT
```

and then you can reset the date column to those values with df = df.date.apply(checkdate)

Comment: Awesome use of `df.col.apply`. Updated my answer with the addition of this, but utilizing [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). +1